# Rails Ancestry gem: remove empty children array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, treeview, ancestry

I am using Bootstrap Treeview with Ancestry gem in my RoR application. When I create a variable:

```
categoriesTree = @categories.arrange_serializable(:order => :name)
```

Each last child includes a subarray with `Children[0]`
[console.log(categoriesTree)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1bn7.png)

The problem is that when Bootstrap Treeview sees subarray it adds '+' sign to the node. Therefore, even nodes without children have '+' signs and it seems like you can expend it when you actually cannot, because it's the last child in the hierarchy.

Please, help me! What would be the best way to create `categoriesTree` variable that would not include `Children[0]` subarray as a last array for each child.

I tried to play around with `cache_depth` ancestry option to see if I can remove last array of children. I added

```
has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
```

but I do not quite understand the syntax of it and just cannot make it work.

**dashboard_controller.rb** (I use gon.categoriesTree because gon gem makes a variable accessible in javascript file.)

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    gon.categoriesTree = @categories.arrange_serializable(:order => :name).to_json
  end
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry :cache_depth => true

    has_many :measures, dependent: :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

**dashboard.js**

```
initSelectableTree = function() {
            return $('#treeview-selectable').treeview({
              data: gon.categoriesTree,
            });
```

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDDjK.png)  Two circled categories should not be expendable (because they are empty), but they are (because `@categories.arrange_serializable(:order => :name)` creates an emty Children array as shown in the first picture)

Comment: Wouldn't Ancestry simply be working with what is in `@categories`? Create the instance without empty associations.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity. Could you explain what you mean by that? :)

Comment: Add your controller code for when you create the variable. Add also your model code if you use anything there, scopes, etc.

Comment: I added my code and a picture with the result I get. Thank you for your time!